# genhtml doesn't generate coverage report after adding --no-external flag to lcov command

Tags: code-coverage, lcov

I wanted to exclude external lib's code from my coverage report, so I've added --no-external flag to lcov command. Unfortunately, after adding this flag genhtml is unable to generate coverage reports.

Command used:

> lcov --directory . -c -o coverage.info -t "coverage_result" --no-external

Result:

> genhtml: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile coverage.info

Also, the coverage.info file looks corrupted:

> TN:coverage_result
>   TN:coverage_result
>   TN:coverage_result
>   TN:coverage_result

Did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: You can try specify `-b` option and pass a path to your sources.

Comment: After some fight with several options I've decided to use another solution with `--remove` option.  
`lcov --directory . -c -o coverage.info -t "coverage_result" -b .`  
`lcov --remove coverage.info "/usr/include/*" "/usr/local/*" "*asio/*" "*googletest/*" -o filtered_coverage.info`